# Joomla JFactory Select

Tags: php, joomla

I have this code trying to get data from a table:

```
<?php
    define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
    define( 'JPATH_BASE', realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../' ));  
    require_once ( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/xampp/hobbies/includes/defines.php' );
    require_once ( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/xampp/hobbies/includes/framework.php' );

    $db =& JFactory::getDbo();
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM vftd8_community_events';

    $db->setQuery($query,0,30);

    $results = $db->loadObjectList();
    if ($db->getErrorNum()) {
         echo $db->getErrorMsg();
         exit;
    }

    return (array) $results;
?>
```

The result set is empty, and the table has data. It does not return errors.
Please I need help. Thanks to you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
// No direct access to this file
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

$db=Jfactory::getDBO();

$select='select * from `#__community_events` ';
$db->setQuery($select);

$res=$db->loadObjectList(); // for multiple records
//$product_data=$db->loadObject(); // for single row records

foreach ($res as $result)
{
   echo $result->id;
   // and whatever you need to print here
}
?>
```

Comment: the code has the same result than my old code, is possible that the problem comes from up?.
I'm not using the code like a module, i dont have helper.php,modulename.php neither the .xml file.
I'm using ajax from the .js main   template file(testing),calling to the only .php file which i shared yesterday.
Can be this reason the cause of my problem?Thank you very much.

Comment: It Works!, copying the modules filosophy,thanks you very much.

Comment: if you got your answer, please approve it. So that everyone else also gets the answer.

Comment: I would suggest you use the proper clauses from the Joomla API rather than writing a raw SQL query like this.